# Change windows Culture Settings or define new using C#

Tags: c#, .net

Can i update the windows culture settings permanently using C#?

Or can i define a new culture in windows using C#?

If yes, then please also provide the code of C# or VB.Net.

I know how to change the culture settings for a project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first question would be why - what is behind this? Changing a clients culture settings seems like a Bad Thing, so I would rather know what the purpose behind this is.

Comment: You should think twice, three, four times before really changing the system Regional settings / culture of Windows permanently. if you absolutely must do so because you are developing a system configuration utility I believe there are some windows APIs for that.

Comment: I dont want to change the user's culture settings. I want to add a new culture that will never be used by the user. But that will be used by the my software. I want to add a new culture at installation time. Then the software will use only that culture. I AM NOT GOING TO CHANGE THE USER'S CULTURE SETTINGS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you want to change the culture setting, you can still run in formatting problems. If the user changes the settings of the culture in windows you still do not know what formatting rules (formatter) you can expect. For example changing the culture before parsing a datetime is a bad practice. If you need to parse a specific formatting, you can better make a formatter like:

```
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
try {
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Good practice is to assume that the users computer has the right formatting for the specific user. Then the user can give the values in the same format as any other program he uses.